# Pycharm not showing complete documentation

Tags: pycharm, documentation

[image]

[image]

Pycharm is not showing complete documentation. The summary string is not being shown neither is the data type. Module documentation is also not working.

Environment -

```
PyCharm 2021.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-213.5744.248, built on November 30, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.13+7-b1751.19 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.11.0-41-generic

Current Desktop: KDE
OS: Kubuntu 20.04
```

Comment: Try file->invalidate caches & restart

Comment: @Gulzar I tried this, did not work

Comment: i think pycharm does not like blank lines :|